# AADSTS50020 can't login to MineCraft

Tags: azure-active-directory, minecraft

[image]

I can't login my account (Microsoft) in MINECRAFT.

**Error:**

> *Sorry, but we re having trouble signing you in. AADSTS50020: User account ' @gmail.com' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist
> in tenant'Microsoft Service'.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error **Sorry, but we re having trouble signing you in. AADSTS50020: User account ' @gmail.com' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant'Microsoft Service'** indicates that you are logging in with a personal Microsoft account.

In order to access **Minecraft: Education Edition**, you'll need to have a Microsoft 365 school or business account with Minecraft Education Edition license